# Laravel Mix and Datatables return $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel Mix to compile down my JS file (contain datatable).

```
$('.table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {targets: 0, orderable: false, searchable: false},
    ]
});
```

But every time I run it the console always return me `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`

at my index.blade.php

```
 <script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js(`resources/assets/js/pages/city.js`, 'public/js/admin/pages/city.js');
```

When I use Laravel Elixir webpack function working normally, but when I change to Laravel Mix it become error.

Any solution?

Comment: Why aren't you compiling and versioning jquery.js and jquery.dataTables.js. I was using Elixir and compiled these into all.js, then just included that in my Blade template. I have just upgraded to 5.4, so will be trying to get Mix working today. I also use Datatables, I will post my webpack.mix.js file later. Mick

Comment: @Mick I have mix version of jquery and jquery.datatables. But still not working that's why I try to init those 2 file seperately to see if its working. But sadly its not. I need to put those $('.table').DataTable() outside any JS. I think something broke it when I run `mix.js()`

Comment: What happens when you run   var table = $('.table').DataTable(), in the console, after the page has finished loading? I am getting a similar error but can initialise when the page has finished loading.

Comment: @Mick if I initiate var table = $('.table').DataTable() outside my js file it works properly (I have initiate jquery file outside it)

Comment: I think this proves that this is a timing issue. The Datatables JS isn't loaded, or the DOM isn't rendered.

Comment: @Mick it's odd if you said its not loaded. I already make sure twice and put timeout function to try it. still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I'll post my solution here.

Below solution worked for me with **Laravel 5.4.**

After integration of the datatables , update your **webpack.mix.js** file as below. Add datatable into **autoload** array and **extract** array.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app-scss.css') 
   .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css/app-less.css')
   .autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'jquery'], 
    validate:'jquery-validation',  
    DataTable : 'datatables.net-bs', 
  })
   .extract([
    'bootstrap-sass',      
    'datatables.net',
    'datatables.net-bs']);
```

Then use it anywhere even inside a blade template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {targets: 0, orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a note on this answer, it only works when datatables and jquery are built into the same file... I am not sure what the point of using webpack is if it is just going to create a 5mb file. More garbage JS tooling.